# SettingWithCopyWarning when adding an empty column to a dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns. I am trying to add a new empty column with this instruction:

```
df['new_col'] = ''
```

column gets added but with a warning:

```
<ipython-input-16-779f11834aea>:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
```

What exactly I am doing wrong? why this warning is triggered?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
df=df.assign(new_col = '')
```